# Problem In Adding an Icon to the Label of a JCheckBox Component

Tags: java

I try to describe an image through HTML tag as follow :

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/checkbox_AddIcon.html

If I use the following HTML tag, it works

```
<html><table cellpadding=0><tr><td><img src=file:C:\user\network-transmit-receive.png/></td><td width=3><td>Hello World</td></tr></table></html>
```

However, when I use the following HTML tag, it doesn't work in Windows XP (I am not sure other Windows)

```
<html><table cellpadding=0><tr><td><img src=file:C:\user directory with space\network-transmit-receive.png/></td><td width=3><td>Hello World</td></tr></table></html>
```

Since there might be possibility user directory name contains space. However can I encode the directory name, so that it is recognized by JCheckBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote your directory names such as

> `<img src="C:\user directory with space\network-transmit-receive.png"/>`

, and also I don't believe "file://" protocol is required. You might want to check out the [HTML](http://w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [XHTML](http://w3schools.com/xhtml/default.asp) (more strict version of HTML which will replace it) tutorials from the W3Schools website. The [W3C Validators](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/) are also useful tools in pinpointing what may be wrong in your page markup.

Comment: new File("C:\user\network-transmit-receive.png").toURI().toURL().toString() will return "file:C:\user\network-transmit-receive.png"

Comment: OK, but if you are specifying it manually in the `<img>` tag, you can do without the `file://` protocol prefix. Wouldn't hurt including it, but point in hand is quotes are required around the file location string in the 'src' attribute.